# Spurious space within number

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130758/dividing-a-square-into-equal-sized-rectangles#comment301707_130758), the penultimate number in the list, $59930$, is displayed (in Firefox $11.0$) with a spurious space between the two $9$s. I made sure I hadn't inadvertently pasted any invisible spaces in the input by selecting the $9$s and overwriting them with two consecutive $9$s typed on the keyboard.

Comment: There is a non-display character between the two 9s. If you copy/paste into a text file it will become apparent.

Comment: @Peter: I'm aware that there is one in the output; that's precisely the problem. What I was saying was that I made sure there wasn't one in the input, so there shouldn't be one in the output.

Comment: @joriki, I did the following experiment. I copied the number from your comment, and pasted it into an empty comment box. It displays the 5 digits without any extra space. But suprisingly it also tells that only '8 more to go'. As the minimum number of characters is 15, I became suspicious. When I went to the end, and started deleting the characters one at a time, the number or required characters started going up (as predicted), '9 more to go', 10, 11, ... at which point the counter was still going up, but the cursor stopped moving. There are still two extra characters between the 9s.

Comment: @Jyrki: You found what Peter found, that there's an extra character in the *output*. As I replied to Peter, not only am I not denying that, that is in fact the problem. There shouldn't be one because I made double sure that there wasn't one in the *input* (which you can't check, of course, which is why I made sure that I checked it). (By the way, I find only one, not two invisible spaces in the output when I copy and paste it.)

Comment: This may not be entirely accurate, but probably related: I think that the MathJaX parser breaks the code into pieces of at most 79 characters that will then be processed. If you look at [this deleted piece of silliness](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3307/) example 2 breaks at the `\b` of `\bigvee` (and it looks like `\b` is interpreted as a LaTeX command in itself); the `b` is the 79th character that was entered without blank space with no possible break point before. If you insert a blank between a comma and a number before the 79th place in your example, the spurious space disappears.

Comment: Yeah, Peter must have seen the same thing. I do get two extra characters. Both in an empty comment box, and also when I paste it into a text editor.

Comment: In the source code of the page with your comment my browser has `9&zwnj;&#8203;9` where the two nines are separated, so two null character entities.

Comment: @t.b.: I see -- that's rather bad, and a lot more general than my case. By the way, glad to see you're back :-) (in case my impression that I'd seen you around less for a while had been right).

Comment: Thanks! :)${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @joriki: I see the same `&zwnj;&#8203;` characters in the page source.  The first is a "zero-width non-joiner" (though I don't really understand what that means), and the second is a "zero-width space".  MathJax does not think of these as belonging within a number, so make the `59` into one number and `930` into another, with two `<mo>` elements in between (in the internal MathML representation), each containing a zero-width character.  Those `<mo>` elements get a little space around them by default, which is where your space is coming from.

Comment: If you didn't add the `&zwnj;&#8203;` entities yourself, then perhaps it is your editor that is doing it.  Are you editing your responses elsewhere and pasting them in, or are you using the SE editor directly?

Comment: &t.b.: you suggest that MathJax is breaking the input at 79 characters, but that is not the case.  I was not able to find the \bigvee on the page you indicated, so I can't check what is going on there, but MathJax has no trouble parsing data that is longer than 79 characters.  I suspect it must be earlier in the pipeline (like perhaps the editor) that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Davide: I produced these numbers as output from a Java program, which I copied and pasted into the comment box. Although there's no reason for that to contain invisible spaces in the middle of a number, when I saw the spurious space, I edited the comment and, as described in the post, selected the two $9$s and typed two consecutive $9$s on the keyboard directly into the comment editor to make sure that there was nothing invisible between those two $9$s in my input. I'll add another comment here where I type the entire text by hand just to make sure.

Comment: first try (with copy and paste)
$1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638,59930,2$

Comment: second try (all typed by hand on the keyboard directly into the comment box)
$1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638,59930,2$

Comment: There was no pasting at any point in that last comment; everything typed by hand and definitely no spaces typed between the two $9$s. Unless there's something very weird going on in my browser in the comment box, you should be able to reproduce that by typing the same thing yourself -- I'll post the raw code for it for convenience.

Comment: Here's the raw text that I typed (basically what you see above except for the dollar signs): `second try (all typed by hand on the keyboard directly into the comment box)
$1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638,59930,2$`

Comment: [This other bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966) I just filed may or may not be related to this one.

Comment: @joriki: The "raw text" comment still contains an invisible U+200C U+200B combination between the two 9's. Did you type that one by hand again?

Comment: I want to try too. This is copy-pasted via an 8-bit terminal window, so absolutly nothing up my sleeve: $1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638,59930,2$ I get a mystery line break in the rendered TeX too, but no extra characters in the edit box when I edit the comment later.

Comment: @joriki: Perhaps the application displaying the numbers generated by the Java program broke the line between the $9$s and added these two characters in the process. Then, when you copied the characters, you picked up these inserted characters inadvertently? There are $79$ characters before the inserted characters, and this seems suspiciously like a broken line.

Comment: @joriki: It must be in the text input or output method site-wide. I tried simply pasting the numbers, without MathJax, without `$...$` on chat, and the 200C and 200B characters were inserted after 79 characters. I even tried starting in a different place and the 200C and 200B inserted 79 characters from the beginning.

Comment: @robjohn: Gee, am I glad that you saw that. I was starting to think that the questions whether I had perhaps inadvertently inserted the spaces myself would never end :-)

Comment: @Henning: I didn't mean to imply that I got extra characters in the edit box; I didn't. The extra characters have always only been in the *output*, never in the *input*; I only mentioned typing over the two $9$s by hand to make double sure there were no invisible space characters between them in the input; there was no implication in that that I had any reason to believe that there were. And what do you mean by "mystery line break"? I'm not so much worried about the line break (which I guess has to come at some point) but about the spaces between the two $9$s on the same line.

Comment: $1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638, 59930,2$ This seems to be the same problem we ran into on chat a while ago. If a string of more than 79 characters without a break are entered, characters are inserted. I simply put a space into the string (in a good spot before character 79) and everything works.

Comment: @DavideCervone: sorry, I falsely assumed that it had something to do with MathJaX because all the instances I saw earlier had MathJaX involved, apparently the cause is a different one as robjohn's answer suggests.

Comment: @tb: easily understood, as the characters would normally go unnoticed. MathJax pays attention to them and so we normally only see their effect when the characters are inserted in $\LaTeX$ source.

Comment: @joriki: "Mystery line break" is the 200C-200B combination which shows up as a forced line break between 59 and 930 in my browser.

Comment: @Henning: The meaning of these characters is indicated in robjohn's answer; they're not a line break, your browser is just using them as an opportunity for a line break; mine shows the whole number on one line, and the characters show up as a space (which apparently they shouldn't if they're meant to be "zero-width").

Comment: @joriki:  I mentioned in an earlier comment why the zero-space characters end up produce space.  They characters themselves are typeset as zero-space characters by MathJax, but they are put in `<mo>` elements in the MathML that MathJax generates, and by default, `<mp>` elements have some space on both sides of them.  *That* is the space you are seeing.  It would be possible to modify what MathJax thinks is allowed as part of a single number to include these characters, but I'm not sure if that is the right thing to do or not.

Comment: I suspect the characters are being added when your answer is processed by Markdown as the HTML page is being created after you submit your comment.  (In particular, MathJax is not introducing the characters.) I thought originally they might have been introduced by the way you were creating your messages, but your "second try" above showed that wasn't true. Your comment to Henning seemed to suggest that even though the characters where there, you shouldn't see a space since they are zero-width.  I tried to say why you *should* see space even though the characters themselves are zero width.

Comment: (Your previous comment that I was replying to seems to have been removed, so perhaps I should remove mine?)

Comment: @Davide: Sorry, I removed it because I hadn't seen your comment under robjohn's answer when I wrote it; but please don't remove yours, it's very helpful; thanks.

Comment: @Rahul: Interesting. There seems to be an attempt to make three roughly equally long lines out of that; the breaks don't occur near the right margin.

Answer (score 10):

**The Problem:**

In a comment to a question or an answer, or on chat, when a string of over 80 characters is entered without [whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), the pair of characters `\unicode{x200C}` [(zero-width non-joiner)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) and `\unicode{x200B}` [(zero-width space)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) is inserted after 80 characters.  This is often bad when it happens in $\LaTeX$ source.

In the [comment in question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130758/dividing-a-square-into-equal-sized-rectangles#comment301707_130758), the following 86 character string appears:

```
$1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638,59930,2$
```

The pair of characters mentioned is inserted after character 80, splitting 59930 into 59 and 930.

**A Workaround:**

There is a fairly simple workaround: insert a whitespace character, if possible, where it will have no effect. For example, just before the 59930:

```
$1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638, 59930,2$
```

Comment: I guess it is Markdown that is inserting the characters?  Certainly adding a space will avoid the issue in general.  For this case, I personally would have done ``$1$, $2$, $2$, $9$, $2$, $46$, ...`` since I consider the commas to be part of the sentence, not part of the math (as suggested by Knuth in the TeXbook).  This will have the advantage of allowing line breaks to occur within the list, whereas if it is all one expression, MathJax will typeset it as an unbreakable box.

Comment: @Davide: That works in this case, but what happens when I want to write an 80-digit number? Arbitrarily inserting spaces where there weren't any in the input seems like something that shouldn't happen quite generally, independent of the possibility of workarounds for particular cases.

Comment: I agree that inserting the characters is a problem.  I was only mentioning here that I think the list of numbers should really be a list of separate math expressions, not a math expression consisting of a list.   Really a different issue.

Comment: For an 80-digit number you can add `\!` where it occurs, or you can add a space after a thousand break. $10.203.040.506.070.809.010.203.040.506.070.809.010.203.040.506.070.809.010.$ $\!203.040.506.070.809.010.203.040$, coded `$10.203.040.506.070.809.010.203.040.506.070.809.010.203.040.506.070.809.010.$ $\!203.040.506.070.809.010.203.040$`. Line breaks _are_ an issue there :).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently in the last 24 hours a new version of the code that connects MathJax with Markdown has been rolled out (see [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3955/7798)).  Let's see if that helps this issue at all:

$1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638,59930,2$

Edit: Yes, it seems to work!  So it appears that this may be a moot point, at least for new answers/questions.

Comment: Let's try in a comment:  $1,2,2,9,2,46,2,250,37,254,2,31052,2,1480,896,306174,2,2097506,2,6025516,6638,59930,2$ Edit:  Drat!  But it does seem that it is specific to comments.  So that suggests that the place where the characters are being added is in the comment-handling code.  That makes sense, since comments only have limited formatting, and don't go through the full Markdown process.  Perhaps there need to be modifications made to help protect math within comments from being modified.

Comment: There's another strange, probably related phenomenon in my browser with the above comment. The line that starts with "Edit:" isn't wrapped; it extends beyond the right margin and is truncated in the middle of the second 'n' in "handling", where the light grid background starts. The next line starts with "limited formatting". [Here's a screen shot.](http://i.imgur.com/zqtHY.png) When I first commented on this, the subsequent refresh of the comments caused the line to be wrapped, but when I deleted the comment the problem reappeared.

Comment: Interesting.  What browser and OS are you using?  It probably has something to do with the in-line equation being wrapped for you (it is not long enough for that to happen for me).

Comment: Yes, it's wrapped; the final $2$ is on a line by itself. Firefox 11.0, Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: OK, I did some checking and it appears to be a bug in Firefox (version 11 at least -- I didn't look at earlier ones).  I will have to look into it further.